# Retrieve input text from a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

In Xcode 4.3 3, I created a button that generates a popup input box with (buttons Cancel & Enter), works ok, how do I retrieve the data entered and display it in a label or a table?

Here is how the code behind my button looks like.

```
- (IBAction)car:(UIButton *) sender

    NSString * title1 = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];

    _mylabel.text = title1;

        UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Expense Amount in $:"
                        message:@"\n\n"
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];


    _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 25)];

    [_textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [_textField setPlaceholder:@"Amount"];

    [prompt addSubview:_textField];

    _textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;


    // show the dialog box
    [prompt show];

    // set cursor and show keyboard
    [_textField becomeFirstResponder];


}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As introduced in iOS 5, you should use the `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` style. You will get your value right in the delegate methods. Don't use a custom textfield anymore.

Comment: Hi jaydee3, thx for your response, I'm new to all this, could help me on how the implementation of this goes? Thx again.

Comment: see this tutorial for implementation: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation/

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to solve here is a regular UITextField input data save, regardless of the alert view. You can accomplish that in different ways and with the use of the UITextField delegate methods:

```
textFieldDidChange
textFieldDoneEditing
textFieldShouldReturn
```

Just implement saving the input data in one of those methods, depends on the desired user experience.

Comment: Hey TommyG, Yes I'am trying to save the input data from a popup input box, not from a regular UITextField. Thx